# Controlling word placement in D3 cloud -- bundling words closer together based on some attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-cloud

I am working on an interactive implementation of a D3 tag cloud that relies on each term having its own category or class. I've managed to include a category attribute to the terms by modifying d3.layout.cloud.js like this:

```
cloud.start = function() {
  var board = zeroArray((size[0] >> 5) * size[1]),
      bounds = null,
      n = words.length,
      i = -1,
      tags = [],
      data = words.map(function(d, i) {
    return {
      // Added by me
      epidem_category: d['epidem_category'],
      other_details: d['other_details'],
      id: d['id'],
      ///////
      text: text.call(this, d, i),
      size: ~~fontSize.call(this, d, i),
      font: font.call(this, d, i),
      rotate: rotate.call(this, d, i),
      padding: cloudPadding.call(this, d, i)
    };
  }).sort(function(a, b) { return b.size - a.size; });
```

I can now access `d.epidem_category` as well as `d.id` when drawing the cloud to give certain categories either a different fill color or rotation value:

```
 canvas
 .selectAll("text")
 .data(words)
 .enter()
 .append("text")
 .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
 .style("font-family", 'Gentium Book Basic')
 .style("fill", function(d, i) { return entity_cloud.set_color(d.epidem_category);})
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 .attr("transform", function(d) {
   return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + entity_cloud.set_rotation(d.epidem_category) ")";
   })
 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.epidem_category })
 .attr("id", function(d, i) { return d.id })
 .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
```

My problem is I would now also like to control the placement of the word as well -- I would like all terms of the same category to appear bundled together in the cloud. I thought maybe I might be able to control this by reordering my input array by category, assuming that the algorithm described on [Jason Davies's tag cloud demo page](http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/#http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=100&q=%7Bword%7D=cloud):

> Attempt to place the word at some starting point: usually near the
>   middle, or somewhere on a central horizontal line.

.. So by that logic, if the first eg 10 words are of the same category, they should appear bundled together somewhere in the middle, the other categories would follow in a circular pattern. Testing this did not produce the anticipated result, however. In fact, I could see hardly any change in the layout at all.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to achieve a layout where terms are bundled together based on some attribute?

Comment: Hi there , What solution did you come up with for this ?

Comment: @Aditya I never found a solution..

Comment: Oh okay, you could have tried using a bounding box (rectangular or circular) ? So what worked for you ultimately?